# Как исправить баг анимации у Isotope filter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Недавно начал пользоваться `Isotope filter` для фильтрации каталога. Но когда попытался добавить к нему `transition` c `border` и `transform`, при переключении фильтра ячейки начали вести себя странно.

Анимация перестановки ячеек проигрываться 2 раза, причем второй раз быстрее первого, [ссылка](https://codepen.io/Incognitus/pen/dKVEyz)

```js
// external js: isotope.pkgd.js

// init Isotope
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.element-item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows'
});
// filter functions
var filterFns = {
  // show if number is greater than 50
  numberGreaterThan50: function() {
    var number = $(this).find('.number').text();
    return parseInt(number, 10) > 50;
  },
  // show if name ends with -ium
  ium: function() {
    var name = $(this).find('.name').text();
    return name.match(/ium$/);
  }
};
// bind filter button click
$('.filters-button-group').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  // use filterFn if matches value
  filterValue = filterFns[filterValue] || filterValue;
  $grid.isotope({
    filter: filterValue
  });
});
// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each(function(i, buttonGroup) {
  var $buttonGroup = $(buttonGroup);
  $buttonGroup.on('click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $(this).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


/* ---- button ---- */

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: #EEE;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( to bottom, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0), hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2));
  color: #222;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #8CF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
  color: #222;
}

.button:active,
.button.is-checked {
  background-color: #28F;
}

.button.is-checked {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}


/* ---- button-group ---- */

.button-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group .button {
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.button-group .button:first-child {
  border-radius: 0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
}

.button-group .button:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
}


/* ---- isotope ---- */

.grid {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}


/* clear fix */

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}


/* ---- .element-item ---- */

.element-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #888;
  color: #262524;
  box-model: border-box;
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in-out, border 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.element-item:hover {
  transform: translate(0px, -7px);
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

.element-item>* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.element-item .name {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 60px;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.element-item .symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.element-item .number {
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 5px;
}

.element-item .weight {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 76px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.element-item.alkali {
  background: #F00;
  background: hsl( 0, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.alkaline-earth {
  background: #F80;
  background: hsl( 36, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.lanthanoid {
  background: #FF0;
  background: hsl( 72, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.actinoid {
  background: #0F0;
  background: hsl( 108, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.transition {
  background: #0F8;
  background: hsl( 144, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.post-transition {
  background: #0FF;
  background: hsl( 180, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.metalloid {
  background: #08F;
  background: hsl( 216, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.diatomic {
  background: #00F;
  background: hsl( 252, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.halogen {
  background: #F0F;
  background: hsl( 288, 100%, 50%);
}

.element-item.noble-gas {
  background: #F08;
  background: hsl( 324, 100%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Isotope - filtering</h1>

<div class="button-group filters-button-group">
  <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="*">show all</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".transition">transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".alkali, .alkaline-earth">alkali and alkaline-earth</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=":not(.transition)">not transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter=".metal:not(.transition)">metal but not transition</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter="numberGreaterThan50">number > 50</button>
  <button class="button" data-filter="ium">name ends with &ndash;ium</button>
</div>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Mercury</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Hg</p>
    <p class="number">80</p>
    <p class="weight">200.59</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Bismuth</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Bi</p>
    <p class="number">83</p>
    <p class="weight">208.980</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Lead</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pb</p>
    <p class="number">82</p>
    <p class="weight">207.2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Gold</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Au</p>
    <p class="number">79</p>
    <p class="weight">196.967</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Potassium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">K</p>
    <p class="number">19</p>
    <p class="weight">39.0983</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkali metal " data-category="alkali">
    <h3 class="name">Sodium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Na</p>
    <p class="number">11</p>
    <p class="weight">22.99</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cadmium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Cd</p>
    <p class="number">48</p>
    <p class="weight">112.411</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item alkaline-earth metal " data-category="alkaline-earth">
    <h3 class="name">Calcium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ca</p>
    <p class="number">20</p>
    <p class="weight">40.078</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Rhenium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Re</p>
    <p class="number">75</p>
    <p class="weight">186.207</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item post-transition metal " data-category="post-transition">
    <h3 class="name">Thallium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Tl</p>
    <p class="number">81</p>
    <p class="weight">204.383</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Antimony</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Sb</p>
    <p class="number">51</p>
    <p class="weight">121.76</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item transition metal " data-category="transition">
    <h3 class="name">Cobalt</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Co</p>
    <p class="number">27</p>
    <p class="weight">58.933</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item lanthanoid metal inner-transition " data-category="lanthanoid">
    <h3 class="name">Ytterbium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Yb</p>
    <p class="number">70</p>
    <p class="weight">173.054</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item noble-gas nonmetal " data-category="noble-gas">
    <h3 class="name">Argon</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Ar</p>
    <p class="number">18</p>
    <p class="weight">39.948</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item diatomic nonmetal " data-category="diatomic">
    <h3 class="name">Nitrogen</h3>
    <p class="symbol">N</p>
    <p class="number">7</p>
    <p class="weight">14.007</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Uranium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">U</p>
    <p class="number">92</p>
    <p class="weight">238.029</p>
  </div>
  <div class="element-item actinoid metal inner-transition " data-category="actinoid">
    <h3 class="name">Plutonium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Pu</p>
    <p class="number">94</p>
    <p class="weight">(244)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: сами напишите , это не сложно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как видите создать фильтр проще простого ...на обычном `hide/show`

только не забываем подключать clearfix в родительский блок `div.item`

```js
$("span.item1").click(function() {
  $("div.item").hide();
  $("div.red").show("fast");
});

$("span.item2").click(function() {
  $("div.item").hide();
  $("div.green").show("fast");
});

$("span.item3").click(function() {
  $("div.item").hide();
  $("div.blue").show("fast");
});

$("span.item4").click(function() {
  $("div.item").hide();
  $("div.yellow").show("fast");
});

$("span.item5").click(function() {
  $("div.item").show("fast");
});
```

```css
span.item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ccc;
}

span.item:hover {
  color: #222;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.items {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

div.item {
  padding: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1px;
}

div.red {
  background: red;
}

div.green {
  background: green;
}

div.blue {
  background: blue;
}

div.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="item item1" title="показать red">item1</span>
<span class="item item2" title="показать green">item2</span>
<span class="item item3" title="показать blue">item3</span>
<span class="item item4" title="показать yellow">item4</span>
<span class="item item5" title="показать все">view all</span>

<div class="items">
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item yellow"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
</div>
```